# Should I use 'been' instead of 'lived' with present perfect?

Tags: tense, verbs

> He has been in London

or

> He has lived in London

Which one is appropriate with 'has'?

Comment: Needs more context or further explanation. Both are acceptable, but mean different things in different contexts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grammatically they're both perfectly fine, but they don't mean the same thing.

> He has been in London

Means that he has visited London before, maybe only for a day.

> He has lived in London

Means that he has had a home in London and stayed there.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "He has been to London" in the first sentence or is "in London" correct ?

Comment: Both are correct. If he has been "to" London, there is a 100% chance he has been "in" London, amd vice versa.